# Synchronization of Threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

You have a storage object O.

Assume you have n reader methods and one writer method in a thread. If the writer method is called by a thread, none of the reader methods should be able to access O, but if a reader method accesses O, any other reader may access O but not the writer. Can I somehow implement this behaviour using "synchronized" statements in Java? If not: How else could I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are basically looking for Locks. Specifically readwrite locks. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html

Answer (score 7):

You could use a [`ReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html).  You allocate it somewhere where the reader and writer threads can access it.  Maybe pass it into their constructors.

```
ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
```

Readers would do:

```
Lock lock = readWriteLock.readLock();
lock.lock();
try {
  // do read operations here...
} finally {
  lock.unlock();
}
```

Writers would do:

```
Lock lock = readWriteLock.writeLock();
lock.lock();
try {
  // do write operations here...
} finally {
  lock.unlock();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Is there a public available Implementation of a ReadWriteLock where I can "atomar" convert a current readlock into a writeLock?

Comment: I know of no such implementation @user1654885.  Sounds to me that you are doing something improper to need that.